# !Undefined control sequence in Lettrine

Tags: lettrine

I am using the following code to Drop a cap with lettrine:

```
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

% Drop Cap
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2 #3 {\ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
    \lettrine[lines=2, findent=1pt, nindent=1pt, slope=4pt]{\StrLeft{#3}{1}}{\@gobble#3}\ }
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\textnormal} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter[Testes para uma ou duas Populações]{Testes para uma \\ou duas Populações}\label{ch:testdpop}
This is an example. \lipsum[1].
\end{document}
```

But I run into this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\xs_StrLeft__ ..._expand \xs_arg_ii }}{}}\xs_call 
                                                  
l.24 This is an example. \lipsum[1].
```

I do get the intended result, but I am puzzled with the error...
Any ideas of why? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the code after `\makeatletter` supposed to do? Please explain.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reppy Mensch. That code "drops-the-cap" of the first letter of the first word in the paragraph after ```\chapter```. In the MWE it's the "T" from the word "This"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xstring` commands are not expandable. You should obtain the first letter before passing it to `\lettrine`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

% Drop Cap
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage{type1cm}% Why? 
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2 #3 {%
  \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
  \StrLeft{#3}{1}[\jpmd@temp]%
  \lettrine[lines=2, findent=1pt, nindent=1pt, slope=4pt]{\jpmd@temp}{\@gobble#3}\ }
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\textnormal} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter[Testes para uma ou duas Populações]{Testes para uma \\ou duas Populações}\label{ch:testdpop}
This is an example. \lipsum[1].
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, this is error prone and explicitly using `\lettrine` is much better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

% Drop Cap
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\start}[1]{\lettrine[lines=2, findent=1pt, nindent=1pt, slope=4pt]{#1}{}}


\begin{document}

\chapter[Testes para uma ou duas Populações]
        {Testes para uma \\ou duas Populações}\label{ch:testdpop}

\start{T}his is an example. \lipsum[1].

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note.** You should never load `type1cm`, which is obsolete. Even less where it doesn't make sense at all, such as with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much egreg!!! It's solved. (I was copying code from stackexchange and I guess the ```type1cm``` package was in some older example (I am a newbie!!)